# Add Harvest Chosen to frontend post plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, jquery-chosen

I'm a newbie so I'm pretty sure the answer to this is probably very simple, but I've tried a lot of different things and still can't get there.

I have a plugin ([Frontier Post](https://wordpress.org/plugins/frontier-post/)) for frontend posting on my Wordpress site. The following code generates a multiselect of post categories:

```
Function frontier_post_tax_multi($tmp_cat_list, $tmp_selected, $tmp_name, $tmp_id, $tmp_size)
{
    $tmp_html = '<select class="frontier_post_dropdown" name="'.$tmp_name.'"id="'.$tmp_id.'" multiple="multiple" size="'.$tmp_size.'">';

    foreach ( $tmp_cat_list as $taxid => $taxname) :
    $tmp_html = $tmp_html.'<option class="fp_multi" value="'.$taxid.'"';

    if ( $tmp_selected && in_array( $taxid, $tmp_selected ) )
    {
        $tmp_html = $tmp_html.' selected="selected"';
    }

    $tmp_html = $tmp_html.'>'.$taxname.'</option>';
    endforeach;
    $tmp_html = $tmp_html.'</select>';
    return $tmp_html;
}
```

This is the switch that calls the function for creating the multiselect depending on settings selected in the admin dashboard:

```
switch ($input_type)
        {

        case "single":
            if (count($tmp_selected) == 0)
                $tmp_selected[0] = '';

            wp_dropdown_categories(array('taxonomy' => $tmp_tax_name, 'id'=>$tmp_field_name, 'exclude' => $exclude_list, 'hide_empty' => 0, 'name' => $tmp_input_field_name, 'orderby' => 'name', 'selected' => $tmp_selected[0], 'hierarchical' => true, 'show_count' => true, 'show_option_none' => __("None", "frontier-post"), 'option_none_value' => '0','class' => 'frontier_post_dropdown'));
            //echo "selected: ".$tmp_selected[0]."<br>";
            break;

        case "multi":
            echo frontier_post_tax_multi($tmp_tax_list , $tmp_selected, $tmp_input_field_name, $tmp_field_name, 10);
            break;

        case "checkbox":
            echo frontier_post_tax_checkbox($tmp_tax_list , $tmp_selected, $tmp_input_field_name, $tmp_field_name);
            break;

        case "radio":
            echo frontier_post_tax_radio($tmp_tax_list , $tmp_selected, $tmp_input_field_name, $tmp_field_name);
            break;

        case "radioline":
            echo frontier_post_tax_radioline($tmp_tax_list , $tmp_selected, $tmp_input_field_name, $tmp_field_name);
            break;

        case "readonly":
            echo frontier_post_tax_readonly($tmp_tax_list , $tmp_selected, $tmp_input_field_name, $tmp_field_name);
            break;
        } // switch
```

I tried echoing the script and using the Chosen file as the source, I tried echoing a script and putting the function inside, I included the chosen file in the php file that holds the above code, I used wp_enqueue_script but no matter what I try, it doesn't display how it's supposed to. I can't figure it out.

This is mostly what I've been trying to do:

```
<script src="chosen.jquery.js"></script>;

<script>
    $(function() {
        $(".frontier_post_dropdown").chosen();
    });
</script>;
```

I changed the class name but it didn't do anything.

I'm not familiar with jQuery and I've seen this `jQuery(document).ready(function(){ jQuery(".chosen").chosen(); });` described as proper usage. Can someone provide some guidance on that?

So, how can I add the Chosen function to this particular multiselect?

Please, help.

(Note: I reached out to the Frontier Post developer but haven't had a response)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a hunch that the problem might be the path to chosen. Also, there is a css file that you need to include to use chosen. Can you replace what you have with this?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.6.2/chosen.min.css"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.6.2/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $(".frontier_post_dropdown").chosen();
    });
</script>
```

You could also try replacing the dollar signs with jQuery to see if that works. Like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.6.2/chosen.min.css"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.6.2/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery(".frontier_post_dropdown").chosen();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It was both the path and the `jQuery`. Now my question is: since my source files aren't local, how would I go about changing the CSS, for example?

Comment: @jetgo You could add a `<style></style>` section after you include the chosen css file and override any default style that you want to change. In fact that is probably the recommended way to change css. It's usually suggested that you don't modify css files that come with a package.

Comment: Yup, figured it out and that's how I'm doing it. Thanks very much.